MIgrating to FCM HTTP V1 APIs - existing registrations are flagged as unregistered
We have been using FCM to gain subscribers for a while now for web apps
An example FCM subscription object gained in our databases looks like this
{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/fqwxWQPWIIc:APA91bH4BzX9cmS3WS_YffyB-Hju4MrPuHET6SLyNO4-dzekgBPMBi6gR2BAjHVTcsTZwu1_FgDANIL_WkmHypc2L7FUJilXI_9idhc5UhQhdFmL_f3h2xMkO_lkkbEbCAoHAXKY1Bmx","keys":{"p256dh":"BCTpxRBJVu5UN48evxqQeK5eRqHB-Xb15oKt03R_DFrGqTc2SQvk9lNYaXJcHN21aG0_mjOZ_F-SRRKFZjkWUVw","auth":"g57rVu4WWKPfYfurHJMv8w"}}

I am able to send notifications to the above subscriber using the legacy FCM API https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send using the authorization, crypto key and encryption headers which are formed via VAPID public and private keys, here I am encrypting the payload and using aesgcm as content encoding.
With the upcoming deprecation I tried sending these via the new FCM V1 endpoint
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project_id/messages:send
In the message body I passed the above sender Id under token as described in the documentation
{
    "message": {
        "token":"fqwxWQPWIIc:APA91bH4BzX9cmS3WS_YffyB-Hju4MrPuHET6SLyNO4-dzekgBPMBi6gR2BAjHVTcsTZwu1_FgDANIL_WkmHypc2L7FUJilXI_9idhc5UhQhdFmL_f3h2xMkO_lkkbEbCAoHAXKY1Bmx",
        "webpush": {
            "notification": {
                "title": "Titre de test",
                "body": "Un contenu de notification",
                "image": ".\/images\/icon.png",
                "badge": ".\/images\/badge.png",
                "icon": ".\/images\/icon256.png",
                "click_action": "\/"
            },
            "data": {
                "time": "1531396372"
            },
            "headers": {
                "TTL": "60"
            }
        }
    }
}

I am also adding the OAuth2.0 token generated from my project's google cloud credentials json file however, the same is giving the following error
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
                "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Expecting this to work since the tokens should be equivalent to subscription ID in the URL, but this is not working


Have you tried to create another user on your test environment?
Check the configs in Google Console Firebase. The client you are using to send the notification should have the role of 'Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent'.
Probably you checked already, but confirm one more time the project ID is correct and corresponds to the settings you are using to authenticate and get the authorization refresh token.

